# Class not found Symfony2

Tags: symfony, ffmpeg, php-extension

I've installed the ffmpeg.so extension on my server. I want to use the ffmpeg-php library in my Symfony 2 application. If I do:

```
$ffmpeg = new ffmpeg_movie('movie.flv');
```

In a standalone php file, it works beautifully. But if I put the same code into my Symfony2 controller, I get

```
Fatal error: Class 'Example\ExampleBundle\Controller\ffmpeg_movie' not found in...
```

It must have to do with Symfony's namespace options, but I'm not sure how to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

When you're within a particular namespace, any class references without a namespace will be treated as a class local to that namespace. In your example, its treating `ffmpeg_movie` as a `Example\ExampleBundle\Controller` namespace class.

If you want to access another namespace, which includes the global namespace (which includes PHP classes, interfaces, as well as any custom defined global items), you have two choices.

1. Access it using it's full namespace (which is `\` for global) & class name:

   ```
   $obj = new \ffmpeg_movie;
   $obj = new \DateTime;
   ```
2. Reference the external class using `use`:

   ```
   use ffmpeg_movie;
   use DateTime as AwesomeDateTimeClass;

   $obj = new ffmpeg_movie;
   $obj = new AwesomeDateTimeClass;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Oops, turns out you can just add

```
use ffmpeg_movie;
```

At the top of your controller, same as any other class. Silly me.